# Vaadin progress indicator for displaying Jenkins build progress

Tags: build, progress-bar, build-process, jenkins, vaadin

I'm developing a Vaadin application that displays build list for each Jenkins job. I want to put a progress indicator to show build progress. Is there a way to find out how much time Jenkins needs to build a specific job for parameterizing the progress bar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [getEstimatedDuration()](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Queue.Executable.html#getEstimatedDuration%28%29) implemented by [Build class](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Build.html). Or (see the comment there) [Executables#getEstimatedDurationFor(Build)](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/queue/Executables.html#getEstimatedDurationFor%28hudson.model.Queue.Executable%29).

Comment: wich jar should I add to use for this class ?

Comment: I've never done it, but as far as I understand everyghin is in jenkins.war

Comment: I'm working on eclipse I need a jar or a web service to use this method but I didn't found anything except this javadoc